# Changing animation speed after 1 second of animation starting in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am using `AimatedPosition` widgets to achieve some animation in flutter , but I want it to start slow then go faster ..I've created variable to be used as duration but it seems is not changing ..check my code :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reg_anim/register_widget_one.dart';
import 'package:reg_anim/register_widget_two.dart';

class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  bool changed = false;


  int speedOne = 10000;
  int speedTwo = 10000;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            //First widget
            AnimatedPositioned(
              top: changed
                  ? 130.0 //related position to top when it is hidden
                  : 120.0,
              //related position to top when it is shown
              right: changed ? 700.00 : 90.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: speedOne),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: Container(
                child: RegisterWidgetOne(),
              ),
            ),
            //Second widget
            AnimatedPositioned(
              top: changed
                  ? 120.0 //related position to top when it is shown
                  : 80.0,
              //related position to top when it is hidden
              right: changed ? 80.00 : -255.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: speedTwo),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: Container(
                child: RegisterWidgetTwo(),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                left: 170,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(
                    changed ? Icons.navigate_before : Icons.navigate_next,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    changed = !changed;
                    setState(() {});
                    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
                      speedOne = 500;
                      speedTwo = 500;
                      setState(() {});
                    });
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `Curves.easeInExpo` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves/easeInExpo-constant.html

Comment: on 1st shoot, it's woking as you described. later on `onPressed` you are chaniging `durarion`, that is also working in my case. you may try `flutter clean` and rebuild, or maybe i didnot get the point, can you describe a little more?